# Wordpress youtube controls off screen

Tags: wordpress, youtube, responsive

I've got a weird issue that I can't seem to find the culprit. When displaying an embedded  youtube player within Wordpress, when a user selects play, the controls are displaying partly off screen. This only happens in Safari. When played in Chrome, there is no issue. What could be causing this?

https://www.antiochchurch.org/truth-and-practice/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is the object fit. Soon as you disable that it works right in safari. Test in Chrome/FF without it and doesn't affect it. It seems like the most current trend.

[image]